# Cloud Connection with Java Window application

Tags: java, database, cloud

I am working on a Record Management System that runs on a cloud database using Java programming Language. Currently, I have the application running on MySQL database. I don't know if anyone can be of help on any opensource cloud SQL platform that can be used.

Comment: This can help [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_database). And we need more details what do you want. As I understand, in your case you can run your MySQL server on a cloud and connect/synchronize it from local machine/device.

Comment: This seems like something that could be answered through general googling.